# How to have multiple add another field on the same web page without each affecting each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to combine all three functions below that add a new field when a user clicks the `add-another` button but I dont want each function to affect one another on the same web page when each button is clicked is there a way I can combine each function together with out each affecting different form fields on the same web page.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-another').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').prepend('<select name="drop_down" class="color"><option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option><option value="blue">Blue</option></select>');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-another').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(0)').prepend('<label class="food"><input type="text" name="food[]" /></label>');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-another').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(0)').prepend('<label class="candy"><input type="text" name="candy[]" /></label>');
    });
});
```

Comment: you can do it inside one $('.add-another').click() of document.ready

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, didn't understand the original question.  You want one function to check which button was clicked and then do something different depending on the button.  The code below assumes each button has it's own id (button1, button2, button3).

```
$('.add-another').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     switch($(this).prop('id')){
         case 'button1':
              //some code for the first button;
              $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(3)').prepend('<select name="drop_down" class="color"><option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option><option value="blue">Blue</option></select>');
              break;
         case 'button2':
              //some code for the second button;
              $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(0)').prepend('<label class="food"><input type="text" name="food[]" /></label>');
              break;
         case 'button3':
              //some code for the third button;
              $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(0)').prepend('<label class="candy"><input type="text" name="candy[]" /></label>');
              break;
     }
     return false;
})
```

Comment: This displays them all at once I want to display the correct field for each unique button when clicked but thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, ok so you need to make the buttons unique by giving them an id and then targeting the id: `$('#myUniqueButton').click(function(e){});`

Comment: Is there a way I can combine them into one function for all three buttons?

Comment: Yes, if you have different unique identification for each button.

Comment: How would I combine all three if I may ask.